# What type of hashes are these and what are salts?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking, salt

These are hashes and salts but I don't know what the salt is. The salts are under the hashes and theyre short.

Also, I don't know how to crack these hashes, can anyone help?

```
--------------+-------------------------+
|     hash    |             salt        |
+-----------------------------------------+-------------------------
$2a$08$.rbdiMmcqXi5Dak8tpt59uicA4KP.SU7dP/bWE7.qahMzyP7FlEXO 57d82dc0ec23d1.34197085
$2a$08$/iqrQJN/xYJ8DNN.QgymBu3Ps4f5eCVs4JhIu7yV/1rzHNzZm2cFO  57d8328c558d81.08589072 
$2a$08$1CejbglJSD98vD03GAh56O7pk0Gkc50UtbO6thOIjeWQLiukS6M4e 57d570135289b4.92894416 
$2a$08$2zByojag7c/UqPjLa9wwmufHtkoy.w/wtWBY3MOyUQqzluaI/..7m 57d831c75d5f08.17633914
$2a$08$3DZfxVHm8awcowlRVLgv6uzqMuRyz5wOTi.q166PucKwsvhrksbhO 57d82c2acc0cf9.95412804
$2a$08$6755nwnGPs2pQfU58gH4z.hl6LUXlaG5dN1q2QtDCzGXgYQ0fSB1i 57d831b5d9ec48.80192755
$2a$08$6n7zGyJbn4KeR.XoFLCgP.6Mls7VTkS8cwYjz0DE2aj4Lydl8Pl66 57d82dca495c31.72152875
$2a$08$75sBkfpTus7oJU4ZR8eJsOdH.CPiLchTC4OrvuvCb4GTUCVv/MCm2 57d832b334e406.58083036
```

Comment: It's part of the long string. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832445/how-can-bcrypt-have-built-in-salts for details, but essentially, the first half of the string between the last $ and the space is salt, and the rest is hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are bcrypt hashes with a loadfactor of 8 ($08$). BCrypt is designed to be slow and so is really hard to crack by brute force. Furthermore the hash of bcrypt after the $08$ is divided in two part :

- an inner random salt
- the hash itself

It means so that the salt you have in your data is an additional one used before using bcrypt. Which is quite useless.

Since the  each hash of Bcrypt have is own random salt, this mean you would need to built a rainbow table for each one.

Unless you want to buy some hardware (probably costly) (it exists some fast FGPA implementation of bcrypt on the net) you just won't be able to do it.

But i'm wondering why would you need to crack those hases ? Can't you override them by generating new values ?

Comment: @Jwan Hussen, to give you an idea, with a load factor of 12 and without specific hardware (like fgpa), you can compute about 1k/s hash. Load factor is about multiplying number of loops by a factor of 2, so for a 8 factor, you should be able to compute 16k/s hashes, with that, you can try a naive dictionnary attack, no more.

Answer (score 3):

I believe those are [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) hashes.

From the link:

> The prefix "$2a$" or "$2b$" (or "$2y$") in a hash string in a shadow
>   password file indicates that hash string is a bcrypt hash in modular
>   crypt format.

This is an unfortunate hash format to have to 'crack'. I've not looked much into the actual real-world efficacy of password dictionaries on Bcrypt hashes, but it is known to be resistant to brute force attacks due to the time it takes to compute a single hash. I expect unless you already have some idea of what the passwords might be, you'll have a lot of trouble.